# Getting multiple emails sent all at once via SNS in AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I am getting multiple emails sent when I only want one email sent every time the function is run.

Reference image:

[image]

However, while reviewing other posts, I made sure there were no additional triggers/destinations set up on function (reference image here of layout):

[image]

Not sure if its in my function since Im using boto3.sns to send to email address. I have to throttle my function after every run. Please reference code below:

```
import json
import psycopg2
import boto3
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from io import StringIO 
import sys
import logging
import os
import csv
import smtplib
from base64 import b64decode

###### Connection Info ######
credential = {
    'dbname' : 'main',
    'host_url' : 'vtest.123.us-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    'port' : '5439',
    'user' : 'user1',
    'password' : '#######'
}


redshift_role = {
    'dev': 'arn:aws:lambda:us-west-1:1###############:function:test_function'
}
###### Connection Info ######

###### Function to load data into S3 and send email out given threshold ######
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  
  ## S3 CONNECTIVITY ## 
  s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
  client = boto3.client('s3')

  conn_string = "dbname='{}' port='{}' user='{}' password='{}' host='{}'"\
  .format(credential['dbname'], credential['port'], credential['user'], credential['password'], credential['host_url'])
  
  sql_query = """with
  tbl as (
  select    
        case 
          when (sa.parentid like '001i0000023STBY%' or sa.ultimate_parent_account__c like '001i0000023STBY%') --Parent OR Ultimate Parent is <Department of Defense> 
          then sa.id 
          else 
            coalesce(sa.ultimate_parent_account__c, sa.parentid, sa.id) end as cust_id,
          (select name from salesforce.account where id=cust_id) as cust_name,
          sa.name as acct_name,
          sa.id as acct_id,
          sa.parentid,
          (select name from salesforce.account where id=sa.parentid) as par_name,
          (select name from salesforce.account where id=sa.ultimate_parent_account__c) as ult_par_name,
          so.id as opp_id,
          so.name as opp_name,
          so.stagename as stg_name,
          so.type as opp_type,
  from
          salesforce.opportunity so
      join 
          salesforce.account sa on
          so.accountid = sa.id
      join salesforce.user su on
        so.ownerid = su.id
      join salesforce.opportunitylineitem sol on
        so.id = sol.opportunityid
      join salesforce.product2 sp on
        sol.product2id = sp.id
      join salesforce.customasset__c sca on
        so.id = sca.opportunity__c
      where 
          so.isdeleted = false
          and sa.isdeleted = false
          and sol.isdeleted = false
  )
  select * from 
  (select
      tbl.acct_name as acct,
     '[' || 'Link' || '](' || concat('https://vectranetworks.lightning.force.com/', tbl.opp_id) || ')' as opp_link,     
      tbl.ca_name,
      tbl.ca_pr_name,
      tbl.ca_mode,
      date(tbl.ca_last_seen) as ca_last_seen,
      tbl.ca_sw_version,
      tbl.ca_tot_hosts,
      tbl.ca_active_hosts,
      tbl
    where
      tbl.stg_name like 'Closed Won%'
      and tbl.arr is not null
    group by
    tbl.acct_name,
    tbl.opp_id,
    tbl.ca_name,
    tbl.ca_pr_name,
    tbl.ca_mode,
    tbl.ca_last_seen,
    tbl.ca_sw_version,
    tbl.ca_tot_hosts,
    tbl.ca_active_hosts) df 

  WHERE ca_last_seen >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
  limit 2"""
  con = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
  filename = '/tmp/Processlist.csv'
  client2 = boto3.client('sns')
  with con.cursor() as cur:
    # Enter the query that you want to execute
    cur.execute(sql_query)
    for row in cur:
      df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cur.fetchall(), columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description])
      df['Time_Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime('now', utc=True)
      df['ca_active_hosts'] = df['ca_active_hosts'].astype('Int64', errors='ignore')
      df['ca_active_hosts'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
      #Save the Query results to a CSV file
      csv_buffer = StringIO()
      df.to_csv(csv_buffer)
      s3_object_name = 'df.csv'
      s3.Object(s3_bucket, s3_object_name).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
      print("Dataframe is saved as CSV in S3 bucket.")
  cur.close()
  con.close()    
      ## Email Portion ## 
  if(df.iloc[0]['ca_active_hosts'] >= 0):
    print('the file is present, going to send notifaction')
    response = client2.publish(
    TopicArn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:############:email-data-lake',
    Message = 'Warning User active_hosts is ' +str(df['ca_active_hosts']) + 'amount at '  +str(df['Time_Stamp']),
    Subject = 'User Warning')
  else:
    print('the file is not present')
      ## Email Portion ##
```

Comment: Check CloudWatch Logs for this Lambda function. It may be failing after sending the email or timing out, in which case the function invocation will be automatically retried multiple times.

Comment: There were no errors/logs showing that unfortunately. Im thinking it has something to do with the code, but unsure why it just keeps sending multiple emails just with new 'timestamps'.

Comment: Look at the invocation request IDs in CloudWatch Logs. Are there repeated request IDs for multiple Lambda function invocations or are they all unique? Maybe inject the request ID into the actual message to SNS to help correlate. The code itself seems to simply publish one message to SNS so either the Lambda function is being invoked multiple times (explicitly or implicitly because of failure retry behavior), or something else is going on downstream.

Comment: There were no errors in the logs, but how many times did the function run? You are missing a return statement, the lack of which I think may be telling Lambda that the function call didn't succeed, so it may be retrying the function.